# Cache.manifest file in MVC 4 bundling

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, caching, bundling-and-minification

I have used bundling for Javascript and CSS files in my MVC 4 application.
Now, whenever I change any of the js/ css file on web server, it doesn't reflect on client's browser until they clear the cache and reload the browser.
The solution I think is to use cache.manifest file, but I am not sure, how should I use that, especially when MVC bundling is used?

Any advice on this much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try appending version=(somenumber). Increment it whenever you modified any file. For example @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/test.js?version=1")

Comment: that would work if I dont use MVC bundling... but as I have used Bundling, this doesn't look a straight-forward one

Comment: adding version will not affect what bundle you have defined in your BundleConfig.cs. For example in your config "bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));" and in your _Layout.cshtml  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css?version=1"). That still gets your bundled file.

Comment: If I do that, I just need to increment "verision=X" whenever I change the underlying javascript or css file?

Comment: yes exactly just increment the number

Comment: @Nirman ... bundling in release mode, by default, adds a version number to prevent caching, and this changes automatically when you change a file...  Why is it not doing this? Are you in release mode? If you choose not to bundle, you can [see this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764617/bundling-is-turned-off-but-i-still-want-versioning/18771697#18771697) on how to manually version.

Comment: that did the trick... thanks Jobert and Mike.. also, add this as an answer and I will mark it.. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the comments from Jobert and Mike :)