# Add cache-buster to non-optimized bundle?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, bundling-and-minification

I'm using Bundling in MVC and have the following:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts.js");
```

When `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true` this renders as:

```
<script src="/bundles/scripts.js?v=RF3ov56782q9Tc_sMO4vwTzfffl16c6bRblXuygjwWE1"></script>
```

When `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false` this renders as:

```
<script src="/js/header.js"></script>
<script src="/js/content.js"></script>
<script src="/js/footer.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to intercept the non-optimized version to include my own custom cache buster?

For example:

```
<script src="/js/header.js?v=12345"></script>
<script src="/js/content.js?v=12345"></script>
<script src="/js/footer.js?v=12345"></script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [bundling is turned off but I still want versioning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764617/bundling-is-turned-off-but-i-still-want-versioning)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you need to? In development, where `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false` nothing is cached anyways, and in production you *should* have `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true` also negating the need for something like this.

**The short answer, is no**, there's nothing built in to allow you to do what you ask, primarily because of the reasons I've already stated: there's simply no need for such a feature.

Comment: Thanks chris, ive got a config to be able to disable optimization in production. Its basically a quick fallback in case the deployment of optimization should cause any unexpected issues. In which case id like to retain the existing cache busters in place. I think ill need to create my own custom mvc helper to do this then. Thanks again.

Comment: @Chris: `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false nothing is cached anyways`, but doesn't the client still cache requests to static js and css files?  If the client has an old file with the same name, it won't make a trip to the server.  Isn't that what version query parameters are supposed to solve by busting the cache, or am I wrong about this?

Comment: @KyleMit: The key point of that statement was "in development". IIS Express sends headers telling the client to not cache resources, because it's development. While true, the client *could* disregard this and cache anyways, all browsers pretty faithfully adhere to the caching requests of the server.

Comment: @Chirs - aha!  That's the piece I was missing to explain why caching would not occur. Thanks!

Comment: Browsers cache differently.  Chrome caches the bundled results in Dev where BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false.  Thus, you are incorrect.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence != proof. I'm also running Chrome in development, and my resources are not cached. Also, there's no such thing as "bundled results in Dev where BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false". Resources are not bundled in dev, so if you're seeing bundled resources, then you're either running in a release config or you don't have EnableOptimizations set to false.

Comment: There is a legitimate reason - when the bundling and minification process breaks the JavaScript, so it's not appropriate to have all the optimisations enabled in production.

Comment: @StuartQ: I'm not even sure what that means. If the bundler is "breaking" your JavaScript, it's probably pretty awful JavaScript. Regardless, the solution is to either not bundle that resource or do your own minification on it, testing to make sure it actually works. Then you can bundle that pre-minified resource instead.

Comment: "in development" also includes deploying development versions to internal IIS for testing by others. Adding cache-bust in these cases are "needed".

Answer (score 0):

Here's an in-depth solution for what you're looking for:

https://volaresystems.com/blog/post/2013/03/18/Combining-JavaScript-bundling-minification-cache-busting-and-easier-debugging

To summarize the cache-busting piece, create a utility method that will concatenate a file creation timestamp of the non-optimized file(s) you want to cache-bust.

E.g.

`<script src="@StaticFile.Version("/js/header.js")"></script>`

This will produce what you're looking for:

```
<script src="/js/header.js?v=12345"></script>
```

**Cache busting utility method:**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Caching;
using System.Web.Hosting;

namespace System.Web.Optimization
{
    public static class StaticFile
    {
        public static string Version(string rootRelativePath)
        {
            if (HttpRuntime.Cache[rootRelativePath] == null)
            {
                var absolutePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(rootRelativePath);
                var lastChangedDateTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(absolutePath);

                if (rootRelativePath.StartsWith("~"))
                {
                    rootRelativePath = rootRelativePath.Substring(1);
                }

                var versionedUrl = rootRelativePath + "?v=" + lastChangedDateTime.Ticks;

                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(rootRelativePath, versionedUrl, new CacheDependency(absolutePath));
            }

            return HttpRuntime.Cache[rootRelativePath] as string;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The System.Web.Optimization.HashCache offers the following extension which adds a hash to the urls.

```
if (!BundleTable.EnableOptimizations)
{
    BundleTable.Bundles.ApplyHashCache
}
```